# Set Invoice style while creating with IPP .NET SDK for QuickBooks v3.0

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am using IPP .NET SDK for QuickBooks v3.0 in my .NET app to exchange the data between my app and QuickBooks Online. I am adding the Invoice using the

```
Intuit.Ipp.DataService.Add<T>(T entity)
```

method. How can is set custom style for the Invoice I am creating?

Answer (score 0):

The style of the invoice is specific to the QBO product.
Using the SDK for QBO v3 services in dotnet, you can only modify the data which shows up in invoices-
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting